# How to build/compile C++, Java and Python projects?

Tags: java, c++, python, build, scons

Let's say I have a bunch of small targets in different programming languages (C++, Java, Python, etc), with inter programming language dependencies (Java project depends on a C++, Python depends on C++). How can one build/compile them?

I tried scons and more recently gyp. I don't remember what issues I had with scons. Gyp has a very ugly language definition plus I had to hack ant scripts in order to build my java targets.

Comment: you what? this question seriously needs more explanation in it

Comment: "best way to build them"?.. thats entirely subjective. I use SCons with fair amount of success.

Comment: I have sought for the answer to this question since I started programming. If you find one, please share. Is it possiblr for users to watch questions and get updated when an answer is chosen in stackoverflow?

Comment: @Yasky: You can click on the "star" to make a question your favorite so that you can go back to it and look at the responses.

Comment: SCons is the tool I reach for for complex builds. It works particularly well for the languages in question.  (Maven appears to be a wonderful kitchen-sink tool if you want to deal with the complexity.  Java IDEs have good support for Ant, but I would hate to have to edit the xml by hand.)

Comment: I meant: imagine you have project C1 in C++, C2 also in C++, J3 and J4 in Java and P5 in python. Imagine C2 depends on C1, J3 on C1, J4 on C2 and J3 and finally P5 in C2 and J4. Now, you want to issue a command line which will build C1, C2, J3, J4 and P5, in the right dependency order, invoking any pre-processor, code-generator, compiler, etc, and everything gets build. On the top of that: that should work for Linux, Mac and Win environments. I achieved that with GYP, Ant and Python. Not an easy task.

Comment: @Terrel - maven actually hides more complexity than it adds, especially if you're open to doing things "the maven way".  Its a wonderful tool and has never seemed overly complex to us.

Comment: @Gatis C1, C2, J3, J4 then P5 is indeed the right order to build these projects as you specified. So if this is a specific [& static] case, you can "hard code" the building process.

Answer (score 2):

I would pick one of the more configurable build tools like ant or maven, as a starting point.

[Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) is highly configurable, and worst case you can use it to exec another build process (like, make, or whatever you normally use for C++).

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) also has a number of plugins natively supported for other languages besides java.  A quick search of the plugins page shows that maven has native support to build C and C++ code, a google search also hinted at 3rd party plugins that will build your python project as well.

While ant is powerful and configurable, I agree that you sometimes have to *hack* ant to get it to do what you want, which is neither clean nor desirable.  Having worked on my project with maven over the past year, I highly recommend it.  We use it to build our java code base, action script front end, run unit and integration tests, and run our database scripts.  Moreover, it has great hooks to our continuous integration tools so the builds we run can be automated.  With a large number of plugins available, we haven't found much that maven can't do for us.

Answer (score 0):

I once checked out CMake (for C++), I liked it very much. It's easy to use yet powerful and quite similar to Make syntax. It also has Java support.

Comment: What about copying and deleting files? Does it create directories as well? How does one tell project dependencies?

Comment: It does support both, but for the details you really need to check out the FAQ. (http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ) CMake has a builtin dependencies scanner but you can also tell CMake the deps explicitely. Check out some simple CMakeLists.txt files here: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/tips/cmake.php